# MongoDB - PHP - How to query and get back intact objects?

Tags: php, mongodb, database

I'm querying a MongoDB database with PHP and what happens is the document response is returned as an array of nested arrays.

Here's a var_dump of the response:

```
Array
(
[_id] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 4ea06851fe90d0662900000a
    )
[name] => Jason A,
[address] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [line1] => 123 Main St
                [city] => Chicago
                [zip] => 60611
                [longitude] => -81.59
                [county] => Cook
                [state] => IL
                [latitude] => 28.32
            )

    )
[kids] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Child One
                [age] => 12
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Child Two
                [age] => 4
            )
    )
)
```

When I query MongoDB via the command console, I can see that the document is stored with the object intact, curly braces and all:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4ea06851fe90d0662900000a"),
"name" : "Jason A",
"address" : {
    "line1":"123 Main St"
    "city" : "Chicago",
    "zip" : "60611",
    "country" : "US",
    "longitude" : -81.59,
    "state" : "IL",
    "latitude" : 28.32
},
"kids" : [
    {
        "name" : "Child One",
        "age" : 12
    },
    {
        "name" : "Child Two",
        "age" : "4"
    }
]
}
```

How can I query MongoDB via PHP and retain the object intact?

Comment: Could you show some of your code and the output you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what's happening correctly, you're seeing "intact objects" in the MongoDB databases, "curly braces and all." These records are actually not much more than standard associative arrays, stored in [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/).

When you insert a PHP object into a MongoDB database, the MongoDB actually converts your PHP object into a sort of associative array, which it then stores as BSON. This is why when you query for your object back, you only receive an "array of arrays."

Try calling [var_dump](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) on the array you get, and see if it contains the data you expected. If not, most likely MongoDB could not properly store the data in your object in BSON.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jonathan.

I've updated my question with sample output. I was wondering though: you can see that it distinguishes between arrays ('kids') and objects (each element of 'kids'), but when I query it with PHP it is all arrays. Is there anyway to retain that 'kids' is still an array but with each 'kid' as a standard object?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible - as I've stated, everything is simply reduced to a structure of nested arrays once it is stored in MongoDB. It sounds like you might be interested in an ORM like Doctrine - ORMs manage storage/retrieval of Plain Old Objects from databases for you.